# symfony disable cache busting

Tags: symfony, caching, toggle

Symfony2 (v2.4) prevent the use of the new "workspace" feature in chrome and CoffeeScript sourcemap for debugging because it comes with cache busting enabled by default.

```html
{% javascripts    
'bundles/js/scriptA.js'
'bundles/js/scriptB.js'
 %}
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset_url }}"></script>
{% endjavascripts %}
```

This will output :

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="/bundles/js/abcde_script_1"></script>
```

Reading the docs they actually explain that we can't configure cache busting to do what they do by default...It is puzzling ! (cf. [Symfony2 documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/framework.html#assets-version-format))

In short would like to have as a result :

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="/bundles/js/scriptA.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/bundles/js/scriptB.js"></script>
```

This problem arose in dev environment

```
RewriteRule (.+) /app_dev.php/$1
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @n.1, hope that I have clarified that way.

Comment: you have this problem in `dev` or `prod` environment?

Comment: @n.1 in the `dev` one. (updated question again)

Answer (score 0):

You can override the debug setting responsible for generating the suffixed assets in a `{% javascripts %}` or `{% stylesheets %}` tag by adding `debug=false`.

```
{% javascripts    
    'bundles/js/scriptA.js'
    'bundles/js/scriptB.js'
    debug=false
 %}
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset_url }}"></script>
{% endjavascripts %}
```

Clear your cache afterwards.

Comment: I can't accept your answer since she doesn't meet the requirements. It does disable debug which in turn generate **one** big file instead of multiple ones as the documentation said. I tested in case you were right but it does what the doc said.